# How can I make a button that scrolls back to the top of the page when you click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

but when your fully at the top it disappears and when you scroll down a but it stays there.

Here is the Javascript for it

```
btnScrollToTop.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
    });

});
```

The arrow button scrolls to the top of the page when you press on it.
[image]

Here is the top of the page
[image]

What I want to do is so when your at the top of the page the button disappears but when you scroll a little it comes back so you can press it. Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: We can't debug images.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

First, add an event listener on the page scroll. In the event handler, change the button display accordingly to scroll position.

Then, set your button display to `none` by default.

Beware: if the user comes back on the page, without scrolling, the button won't be shown even if the page is scrolled. To prevent this, call the event handler on page load.

```
const scrollHandler = () => {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY 
  if ( scrollPosition > 0) {
    btnScrollTop.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    btnScrollTop.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
window.onload = scrollHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) would probably be the right approach.

**Code Description:** What the code below is doing here is - changing the CSS display property of the element with ID `buttonID` to `none` when the element with ID `topSectionID` is 100% visible on the screen.

```js
const topSection = document.getElementById("topSectionID");
let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 1.0,
};

let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            document.getElementById("buttonID").style.display = 'none'
        } else {
            document.getElementById("buttonID").style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
observer.observe(topSection);
```

Here `threshold: 1.0` means - execute the intersection observer when 100% of the `topSectionID` is visible

Comment: So do I just replace my current javascript with that?

Comment: This needs to be added along with the evenlistener. But yes, you should be able to copy it. If you see any error in the browser console, you should be able to debug it easily.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I want to make it so the arrow that scrolls up when you press it is hidden when your at the top of the page. But when you scroll a little bit it appears.

Comment: You need to update the `topSectionID` and `buttonID` based on you HTML. Check out some introductory videos for Intersection Observer. Its an interesting concept and will help you in long run. Also read the "**Code Description**" section in my answer, it explains what the code is doing

Comment: It still doesn't do anything when I do that. In Fact it doesn't even scroll up when I press it when I add that code.

Comment: Check the browser console for any errors and try to debug them.

Comment: It says btnscrolltotop has already been declared

Comment: Try to google for it and debug it. This is a really small issue with variable re-declaration.

Comment: I could not find the solution could you please tell me what do to?